# Setup AWS Cloudfront with my AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

my server is running off a EC2 instance. I followed the docs for Cloudfront and set the origin server as the ec2 server with url ec2-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

My problem that I'm facing is that whenever I post an article onto my server via a cms, or even loginto admin access (a POST by the browser), the address instead of www.example.com/test becomes ec2-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/test and the authentication doesn't happen.

So I tried placing a redirect in my .htaccess file to redirect ec2-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com to www.example.com (302?).

However in that setup the browser says "Too many redirects" and refuses to open my site's homepage.

So my cloudfront setup is not working. Anyone who would be willing to help me? Thanks so much!

Comment: One possibility: [Configure CloudFront to forward the original `Host` header to the back-end](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38288678/1695906).  Please confirm, since this is a possible duplicate, but I don't want to close it as such if it isn't.

Comment: Can you tell me the details of steps to take in aws console? Thanks!

Comment: Really?  Click the link in the answer, and scroll down the page of the provided documentation to "Whitelist Headers."  The setting is on the Cache Behaviors tab after you open the behavior to edit it.

Comment: Sorry but I checked the link you gave but just let me know exactly what values to whitelist I'm grateful

Comment: Sorry I'm an aws newbie sort of.. :-)

Comment: Can someone please give me the exact solution and steps? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what values to whitelist? Select `Host`.  The `Host` header, as mentioned above, is what you need to whitelist.  Select it in the box on the left, click the arrow so it appears in the box on the right, save changes, wait about 20 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Michael I'll give it a shot later this week

Comment: Hi Michael do i have to add whitelist for every behavior?

Comment: Any behavior where it's appropriate should be modified.

Comment: Thanks so much Michael your tips helped me setup cloudfront on my server 