# Cloudfront intermittent errors: 504's, too many redirects?

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Rails app with an NGINX reverse proxy, and I am serving it on AWS. I have NGINX set to direct all traffic to HTTPS.  The app and NGINX are on an EC2 behind an Elastic Load Balancer, and I'm terminating SSL on the ELB. When I point the domain at the ELB, the app works great, and the SSL redirecting works as expected.

I'm trying to use CloudFront, with the ELB as the CloudFront origin. When I point the domain at CloudFront, I get one of the following:

- A `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error on Chrome
- Some of the assets on the page will load and some won't. One page will load the CSS but no images, on another page the images but no CSS. The missing assets will have a 504 error code.

It's not the certificate (I generated it from Amazon) and I don't think it's my CloudFront setup, since I'm using the exact same setup on a different app with no issues.

I think it's my NGINX setup, though I don't know why it would work on the ELB but not CloudFront. But I'm new to NGINX and may be doing something wrong. Here's my `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {

}

http {
    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_disable      "msie6";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/json
                      application/atom+xml;

    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=APP:100m inactive=24h max_size=2g;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$request_uri";
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    upstream rails_app  {
      server app:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        root /var/www/html;

        location / {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_next_upstream error;

          if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
          }

          try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|svg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|woff|woff2|map)$ {
            proxy_cache APP;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 5m;
            proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control";
            expires 1d;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

            proxy_pass http://rails_app;
        }

        location @proxy {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

            proxy_pass  http://rails_app;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you see anything that would make CloudFront choke on this?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this error on non-Chrome browsers?

Comment: Yes, it's probably doing that on Safari too, it just looks different--Chrome actually says "TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" but on Safari I sometimes get the CloudFront error page, or the sometimes-missing-assets issue.

Comment: The question is different but I suspect the answer is the same: you may need to [configure CloudFront to forward the incoming `Host:` header to the origin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38288678/1695906).     Otherwise your web server may see the ELB hostname in the incomimg request and try to redirect the browser to the "correct" hostname -- which is what the browser already requested... redirect loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I double-checked my CloudFront settings, and I am indeed forwarding the Host header to the origin. How about the rewrite rule though--should I be rewriting to `$server_name`, or `$host`?