# Spring Hatoeas ControllerLinkBuilder proxy

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cloudfront, hateoas

There are two things:

1) My application is deployed on AWS cloud using a ELB (load balancer) and CloudFront. Current flow is: User access public URL of CloudFront -> CloudFront redirects it to my ELB.

2) I'm using Spring Hatoeas to constructs my API response, especially using ControllerLinkBuilder to obtain the URL of the controller method.

Now the issue comes.
When I try to call the API on the public URL of CloudFront, I get the ELB URL instead of the public URL of CloudFront in my response:

```
{
 "something": "something",
 "_links": {
    "something": {
        "href": "http://{elb_url}/api/something"
    }
 }
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
 "something": "something",
 "_links": {
    "something": {
        "href": "https://{public_cloudfront_url}/api/something"
    }
 }
}
```

Because the application is actually deployed on the ELB URL and not the public CloudFront URL...

Comment: Similar question, possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38288678/1695906

Comment: Answered by Michael.
More information see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38288678/1695906

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Cloudfront + Load Balancer, url changes from main domain to load balancer subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286901/aws-cloudfront-load-balancer-url-changes-from-main-domain-to-load-balancer-su)