# URL changes when cloudtrail redirects to elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-eks, nlb

I have EKS with a web app hosted on it, with a load balancer on top.
In addition, Route53 DNS name points to a CloudFront distribution that redirects to the load balancer. The issue is whenever the redirection happens, the URL on the browser changes from the Route53 URL to the default ELB endpoint.

How can I make the URL not get changed?

Comment: You mean cloudfront? Have a look at this, add Origin and Referrer header if it still not work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399672/how-to-have-an-aws-elb-forward-the-actual-host-name-to-the-target-group-instead

Comment: unfortunately, after adding this headers, I'm just getting 404 error

Comment: Time to debug your load balancer and eks then.