# To point a domain to the correct address: domain-cloudfront-loadbalance-ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Currently, my system is being built on WordPress and hosted on AWS Cloud with the architectural model

Domain (example.com) -> cloudfront (example.cloudfront.net) -> load balance (alb.elb.amazonaws.com) -> Web System.

Now, the system is running smoothly; however, there is an issue where when I access the website via the domain name (example.com), it resolves to the load balancer's address (alb.elb.amazonaws.com).

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjsp1.png)

Could anyone help me, please?

I checked on route 53
Cloudfront:

- Origin/Behaviors pointer Load balance
  ...

Comment: That's not "resolving" to the load balancer's address, that is **redirecting** to the load balancer's address. Any time you see a domain name change in the browser URL bar, it is because of an HTTP redirect, not DNS resolution. You need to check your host name settings in Wordpress to make sure it's not issuing redirects.

Comment: Please share the configuration of Route 53 if possible, it looks to be a routing issue.

Comment: @atish.s Thank you for your response, here is my Route 53. Can you please take a look? https://imgur.com/a/PUN5dqb

Comment: @MarkB When I configure the hostname in the WordPress settings, setting the domain, the website keeps reloading multiple times (redirecting). Can you please take a look? https://imgur.com/a/JoXmPSB

Comment: See the answer below, it sounds like an issue with the host header not making it to the wordpress server.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, I have received the answer, but a new issue has arisen. Can you help me as described below?

Answer (score 0):

Usually if your DNS record is not resolving to an IP address, it is a `CNAME` record instead of an `A` record.

The issue is however not with the DNS, it looks to be mostly with cloudfront itself. Cloudfront seems to set the `Host` header to the load balancer's URL which eventually causes a redirect to the load balancer's URL.

I found this question and answer to be the same as yours.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193292/6200354

The solution to the issue is allow the original `Host` header to be passed to the server.

A detailed explanation on how to do it can be found on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69412213/6200354).

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I followed the instructions, and it worked perfectly. Can I ask you another question? The website is accessible now, but when I try to access other pages like domain.com/wp-admin, it doesn't work. I have looked at some guides, but I still don't quite understand. Could you please guide me? Thank you very much. https://aws.amazon.com/vi/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/

Comment: It looks to be a misconfiguration on cloudfront. `wp-admin` is usually pointing to your server where your application is hosted. You must configure cloudfront to redirect traffic for `wp-admin` to your server.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i have config wp-admin with the setting below, could you please check, thank @atish.s https://imgur.com/a/upgDKZj

Comment: Maybe it would be best to post a new question and mark this one as resolved since the answer to the question you asked, has been provided and worked as well.