# Paths won't resolve in domain name but in Elastic Beanstalk URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

### What I have done so far:

- I uploaded my Laravel App to Elastic Beanstalk
- I purchased a domain name at namecheap: `domain.net`
- I set up a Hosted Zone for domain.net in Route 53
- I entered the NS infos from the Hosted Zone in the section of my domain at namecheap
- I got a certificate from Certificate Manager and associated `domain.net`, I got a second cert for `*.domain.net`
- I created a CNAME record for the certificate in the Hosted Zone (see picture below)
- I created a CloudFront distribution, under "Origin Domain Name" I put the Elastic Beanstalk URL, chose "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS", entered `domain.net` unter "Alternate Domain Names" and chose the SSL cert for `domain.net`
- I repeated the previous step for `*.domain.net`
- Then in Hosted Zones I created an Alias record for `domain.net` pointing to the CloudFront distribution for `domain.net` and another Alias record for `*.domain.net` pointing to the respective CloudFront distribution (see picture below)

### Question

I went on the website and got an SSL connection for both `domain.net` and `www.domain.net`, even the redirection from HTTP to HTTPS works. But when I click on a link in the navigation menu for example, like "About", the page I get is **NOT** `domain.net/about`, but `http://myenvironment-env.eba-zxsw5igy.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/about` with a "Not Secure" connection. When I enter the URL manually in the browser, however, like `domain.net/about`, I get the correct URL. What may I have done wrong?

Here is the overview over the records from the Hosted Zone.
[image]

### Update

Configuring Route 53 with the same Laravel application code on Elastic Beanstalk without SSL (+CloudFront) works fine. I am able to access any links on the website, they resolve correctly to `domain.net/about` etc.

Maybe I do not connect CloudFront to Elastic Beanstalk correctly? Again, this is what I do in the CloudFront distibution: Under "Origin Domain Name" I put the Elastic Beanstalk URL, I choose "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS", I enter `domain.net` unter "Alternate Domain Names" and chose the SSL cert for `domain.net`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this issue isn't related to AWS, but to how you are building the links inside your application.

Comment: I have read that too, but the thing is, I have had linked my domain name to EBS before with the same application code and the links resolved in the correct URLs. Unfortunately I deleted the old Hosted Zone and don't have any settings (shouldn't have done that). Right now I only wanted to set it up again with SSL. Can the problem lie in creating a record for the EBS URL in the Hosted Zone? I am clueless.

Comment: No, you need to configure your software on the server to be aware of the domain name it should use to build links. This isn't a Route53 issue.

Comment: I don't know if this will answer your question as there are many moving parts involved. Have a look at this document, if you haven't already. Maybe it helps solve the issue: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to use a Load Balancer but CloudFront with Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution for my problem. By default, CloudFront sets HTTP Request Header to the origin hostname -- for me this was the ElasticBeanstalk URL. The application then generates links based on that origin.

To change that behavior one has to create a Cache Policy and an Origin Request Policy and add the host header to a whitelist, so CloudFront uses the hist header that is sent from the browser.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38288678/9994944) gave me a hint on what to do, as well as these AWS resources:

- This gives an [overview](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-cloudfront-to-forward-headers/) about the solution
- How to create a [Cache Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-the-cache-key.html#cache-key-create-cache-policy) and attach it to your distribution
- How to create an [Origin Request Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-origin-requests.html#origin-request-create-origin-request-policy) and attach it to your distribution