# AWS CloudFront to EC2 end-to-end encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I need the end-to-end encryption, so current the setup is:

```
example.com -> Route53 -> LB (TCP :80/443) -> Nginx Ingress with SSL certs installed
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
example.com -> Route53 -> CloudFront -> LB (TCP :80/443) -> Nginx Ingress with SSL certs installed
```

When I'm attaching the same certificate to CloudFront, I'm getting a 502 CloudFront error. I listed `example.com` in Alternate Domain Names and LB DNS name `mylb123.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` as Origin Domain Name. Documentation [says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html) that Origin Domain Name should match one of the names in SSL certificate that is assigned to the origin, but the SSL was provisioned for real domains like `example.com`, for sure it does not include `*.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` etc. This confuses me.

Can you please suggest on how to setup SSL on CloudFormation side or passthrough it and handle SSL on Ingress side?

**Update:**

The SSL certificate is issued by DigiCert, it's not self-signed.

Comment: It is possible. But, can you just update/change the certificate?

Comment: The certificate was provisioned by DigiCert for usage on EC2 instance side since end-to-end encryption is required. I don't think that include `*.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` to that certificated is a good option, isn't it?

Comment: @jumpy You can't use your `DigiCert` cert for `*.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` because this domain is not yours. You need to have your own domain. I don't understand how you could register a cert for AWS-owned domain? Whatever you did, such cert is invalid.

Comment: You right, I can't. DigiCert certificate is provisioned for `example.com`, but when I use it for CloudFront it raises `502` error. The problem was in SSL handshakes falling between CloudFront and Nginx instance. I had to whitelist the `Host` header so CloudFront can forward it to the origin, see me answer below. Thanks for your support anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution in a [non-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286901/aws-cloudfront-load-balancer-url-changes-from-main-domain-to-load-balancer-su).

To make SSL work without `502 ERROR The request could not be satisfied` error, I had to specify my domain (e.g. `example.com`) as Alternate Domain Name in CloudFront distribution, attach the SSL certificate provisioned for `example.com` and, very important, whitelist `Host`  header in the cache behavior. This makes SSL handshakes work between CloudFront and Nginx.

Answer (score -1):

For your origin, in your case instance, you must have **valid public SSL certificate**. It can't be self-signed. This means that you need to have a proper, public domain for which you register such a certificate.

AWS ACM free SSL certs do not work with instances, unless in enclate, so you have to use a **third party** to get such an SSL certificate. Popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/. Alternatively, you can front your instance with ALB and get free SSL from ACM.

Comment: The SSL certificate has been issued by DigiCert for usage on the Nginx instance side since end-to-end encryption is required. So it's not a self-signed certificate, I had to mention this, sorry. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!